# Unable to run compiled jar file

Tags: java, jar, classpath

so I am making a program that implements the LWJGL library for controller input. it's the only library I use in this that is not built into java. it wont run when i double click it, and it gives me the following intersting errors when I run it from the command line with java -jar

```
WARNING: Found unknown Windows version: Windows 7
Attempting to use default windows plug-in.
Loading: net.java.games.input.DirectAndRawInputEnvironmentPlugin
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jinput-dx8_64 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
```

I think it's a problem in the classpath, but I'm not entirely sure.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

it won't let me answer my own question, but I figured it out. I needed to put the DLL files that came with JInput into the same directory as my JAR file

Answer (score 0):

I think the native libraries should be distributed together with your lwjgl lib, but if not, download the missing file from [here](https://projectsforge.org/projects/bundles/export/8/tags/0.0.1/jinput-2.0.6-r246/src/main/resources/jinput-dx8_64.dll) for example and put it in your classpath either by putting it in the same directory as your project, or adding it as a native library to your lwjgl jar (in eclipse), or by using `-classpath` when trying to run the jar.